# media query 1 by 1 pixels

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm searching for a way to bundle my media queries. I'd like to change the `top` via a media query. It should be +1px for every pixel of the window height.
So I have a red box that shall be away from the top by 300px on my window. my window is 577px high. If I lower the height of my window, the top value should be 1 pixel lower for every pixel the window is lower.

Is there a way to do that without typing like 400 queries by hand?

Comment: Research the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function in CSS. Use that to create a calculation you can perform on the UI rather than manually creating a potentially infinite number of media queries.

Comment: Your description makes it sound as though you just want the top to be 100vh. Could you explain in more detail what is actually required?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.